# PHPStorm takes forever to compact indices on a Mac

Tags: mac, phpstorm

Has anybody experienced this? I'm running PHPStorm in 32-bit mode but it still takes about 7mins to fully initialise on a 2.2GHz i7 with 10GB memory.

This seems highly irregular.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What particular project do you open?

Comment: How do you mean? A PHP project…?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem using WebStorm6 and the solution was to clear the cache. Check http://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-181 to see, depending on your OS the location of the Cache folder.

Comment: I must say that with PHPStorm 7, things have significantly improved.